# Angular 1.6 - preventing ng-repeat if not object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my code I recieve sone info from the server and present it to the user. The thing is, that info can be either a string or an object. If the data is a string it is still presented but angular is trying to iterate over that string and throws an error if there are "duplicated key". Is there an option to prevent angular from running the `ng-repeat` if the variable in question is a plain string?
**In the following example `$ctrl.details` can be an object or a string. If its a string I just want to show it inside, without initiating the `ng-repeat` loop.**
The HTML:

```
        <div ng-repeat="details in $ctrl.details">
            <strong>{{:: details.title}}</strong>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="value in details.detailsRows">
                    <strong>{{:: value.title}}</strong>
                    <a ng-href="{{:: value.value }}" ng-if="value.isLink" target="_blank">{{:: value.value }}</a>
                    <img ng-src="{{:: value.value }}" ng-if="value.isImage" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369292/how-to-check-for-data-type-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Prefer solving problems in Javascript than in markup:

```
...
if (angular.isString(vm.details)) {
  vm.strDetails = vm.details;
  vm.details = [];
} else {
  vm.strDetails = '';
}

{{$ctrl.strDetails}}
<div ng-repeat="details in $ctrl.details">
```